# How to get URL value in drupal?

Tags: webforms

My URL is something like this http://xyz.com/content/show-cat?catid=2  . Now i want the value of catid (i.e 2) and save it in a variable. I wrote php code like $store=$_Get['catid'];

But this format is not accepted in drupal. How can i implement this? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$store=$_GET['catid'];` instead as PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: also, for security when pulling things straight out of $_GET please make sure to stick it in check_plain() or similar before using the value.